# How to display different comment sets for a commenting component? (VueJS, Firebase)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, comments, social-media

I'm trying to create a social media app with comments on each post.

I can display comments, but each post displays the same set of comments.

I'm struggling to figure out how I can display different sets of comments on each post.

Would really appreciate help!

Github code [here](https://github.com/ts3486/chobihige/tree/master/src/components)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is behind links, which means it can't be searched by people who have the same question as you in the future. Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem you have here: you should add some method of separation between comments on different posts.

#### Example:

Without separation:

1. A user > Nice post
2. User 2 > This is a cool post
3. The 3rd > Wow, cool!
4. A user > Nice post
5. User 5 > This is a cool post
6. The 6th > Wow, cool!
7. A user > Nice post
8. User 8 > This is a cool post
9. The 9th > Wow, cool!

With separation:

1. Post 1 > A user > Nice post
2. Post 3 > User 2 > This is a cool post
3. Post 2 > The 3rd > Wow, cool!
4. Post 3 > A user > Nice post
5. Post 1 > User 5 > This is a cool post
6. Post 2 > The 6th > Wow, cool!
7. Post 2 > A user > Nice post
8. Post 1 > User 8 > This is a cool post
9. Post 3 > The 9th > Wow, cool!

#### How to fix:

Add a match for a post id, and add the post ids to each post.

And change the script in CommentForm.vue with this:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: null,
      comment: null,
      post: null,
    };
  },
  name: "CommentForm",
  methods: {
    onPost() {
      let commentContent = {
        name: this.username,
        comment: this.comment,
        post: this.post
      };
      this.$emit("comment-posted", commentContent),
        (this.username = null),
        (this.comment = null),
        (this.post = null);
    },
  },
};
```